# Can map function index start with an increment?

Tags: javascript

Can a map function index start with an increment say 50 instead of ZERO?

```
data.map((row, index+50 ) => (
       console.log(index); //should return values 50, 51, 52....
));
```

The reason to not do (index+50) within map is simply because the index used in multiple lines of code within map function, it would be convenient to have the index start with this increment instead of having to add 50 everywhere.

Comment: Just write `index += 50;` at the top of the function.

Answer (score 1):

No it can't, but you can achieve what you want:

```
data.map((row, index ) => (
       console.log(index+50); //should return values 50, 51, 52....
));
```

Or optionally:

```
data.map((row, index ) => (
       let newIndex = 50 + index;
       console.log(newIndex); //should return values 50, 51, 52....
));
```

This way you can use `newIndex` 'every where' without changing it now and then

Answer (score 0):

how bout just doing this

```
data.map((row, index ) => (
       let highIndex = index >= 50;
       if(highIndex){
           //do stuff
       }
));
```